# How to make a virues free exe (C# application) in advance installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, exe, advanced-installer

I have develop a media player in windows application c#,
after making the application I have make a setup by using the advance Installer.
but when I run the setup the antivirus block the EXE setup.

So how can make virus free EXE setup..?

Comment: Have you ever heard about _false-positives_? Your installer doesn't have a virus, but your AntiVirus application _thinks_ it does. AVs are not 100% accurate you know. --- Also, if it's Norton: it reacts to almost everything.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have anti-virus systems ignore your application (or any application really, assuming it is not malicious) is to submit a false positive report with your attached file so that they can review it.

Here are some false positive submission links:

Avast: https://www.avast.com/false-positive-file-form.php

Symantec/Norton: https://submit.symantec.com/false_positive/

AVG: http://www.avg.com/submit-sample